# Unit testing a C library with GoogleTest and CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, googletest

I cannot seem to get a library I'm building to link properly against my GoogleTest unit-test binary. It fails during the linking phase of the build:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../target/unit_tests
cd /Users/ebenoist/development/mylib/build/test && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script      CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/link.txt --verbose=0
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "a_function_in_my_lib(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      test_my_lib_AssertionTrue_Test::TestBody() in unit_tests.cc.o
```

I have a project with the following structure:

```
|-- src
|   | -- mylib.c
|   | -- mylib.h
|   | -- mylibcli.c
|-- build
|   | ... CMakeStuff
|-- target
|   | -- mylib.a
|-- test
|   | -- unit_tests.cc
```

The CMakeList.txt in my test directory looks like this:

```
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${COMMON_INCLUDES})
set(test_sources unit_tests.cc)

add_executable(unit_tests ${test_sources})
target_link_libraries(unit_tests gtest gtest_main mylib)

add_test(unit-tests unit_tests)
```

I know the function exists and the library is compiling well because I have an executable that is built against the library in my src/ as well.

**How do I get my unit tests to properly link against a library that I am building?**

For more reference:

*The CMakeLists.txt in src/*

```
include_directories(${COMMON_INCLUDES})

# LIBRARY
add_library(mylib STATIC mylib.c)

# CLI TOOL
add_executable(mylibcli mylibcli.c)
target_link_libraries (mylibcli mylib)
```

*The CMakeLists.txt in /*

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (mylib)

enable_testing()

option(test "Build all tests." OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../target)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../target)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../target)

set(COMMON_INCLUDES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

add_subdirectory(src)

if (test)
  add_subdirectory(vendor/gtest-1.7.0)
  add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` will help you to determine which symbols exactly are undefined

Comment: The above output is from a make VERBOSE=1. The undefined symbol is defined in the library I'm attempting to link to. This works with the CLI, but does not work with my unit test.

Comment: `VERBOSE=1` echoes the actual link command.  If it does link and in correct order then check to see that the symbol in unit_test.cc.o matches symbol defined in libmylib.so (relevant command is `nm` if you aren't familiar already).

Comment: This is the complete link output: ```cd /Users/ebenoist/development/mylib/build/test && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/unit_tests.cc.o  -o ../../target/unit_tests  ../../target/libgtest.a ../../target/libgtest_main.a ../../target/mylib.a ../../target/libgtest.a -lusb-1.0
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be compiling the 32 bit binary (the "-arch x86_64" option is nowhere to be seen) but trying to use the 64-bit version of Google Test.

Comment: Adding explicit -m64 and -arch x86_64 to both the CFLAGS and CXX_FLAGS has no effect. ```set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m64 -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -g3 -Wall -O0  -arch x86_64")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -m64 -arch x86_64")
```